# How to write a multicharacter literal to a file in C++?

Tags: c++, char, fstream

I have a structure defined array of objects with different data types, I'm trying to write the contents to a file but one of the char values is more than one character, and it's only writing the last character in the multicharacter literal to the file. The value in the char is 'A-', but only - is getting written. Is it possible to write the entirety of it? Before anybody suggests just using a string, I am required to use the char data type for Grade.

The code I have looks like this:

```cpp
//Assignment12Program1
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//Structure with student info
struct studentInfo   
{
    char Name[100];
    int Age;
    double GPA;
    char Grade;
};

//Main function
int main() {
    //Sets number of students in manually made array
    const int NUM_STUDENTS = 4;
    //Array with students created by me
    studentInfo students[NUM_STUDENTS] = { 
        {"Jake", 23, 3.45, 'A-'},
        {"Erica", 22, 3.14, 'B'},
        {"Clay", 21, 2.80, 'C'},
        {"Andrew", 18, 4.00, 'A'}
    };

    //defines datafile object
    fstream dataFile;
    //Opens file for writing
    dataFile.open("studentsOutput.txt", ios::out);
    //Loop to write each student in the array to the file
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        dataFile << students[i].Age << " " << setprecision(3) << fixed << students[i].GPA << " " << students[i].Grade << " " << students[i].Name << "\n";
    }
    dataFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

And the text file ends up displaying this:

```
23 3.450 - Jake
22 3.140 B Erica
21 2.800 C Clay
18 4.000 A Andrew
```

Comment: Multicharacter literals are `int`s, not `char`s.  You can't fit two characters into one `char`.

Comment: `'A-'` can't be stored in `studentInfo::Grade`, just single character.

Comment: In addition multichar-literals have implemented specific values (`'A-'` is not necessary `'A' << 8 + '-'` (and it is not even a endianness issue)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to fit two characters in a single byte `char`. The simplest solution is to modify the data structure:

```cpp
struct studentInfo {
    .
    .
    char Grade[3]; // +1 for a null-terminator
};
```

Then, you have to place `A-` in double-quotes like this:

```cpp
studentInfo students[NUM_STUDENTS] = {
    { "Jake", 23, 3.45, "A-" },
    { "Erica", 22, 3.14, 'B' },
    { "Clay", 21, 2.80, 'C' },
    { "Andrew", 18, 4.00, 'A' }
};
```